# make item not affected by css, but let it affect other items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This may seem like a strange question: I have an image I would like to use as a header. My entire website is centered with `vertical-align: center`, but I would like the header image to be at the top of the screen. I know I have to use either `position: relative` or `position: absolute` for the image, and then add `vertical-align: top`. If I try relative, the image stays centered, but when I try absolute, the text on the page overlaps with the image. I am using Bootstrap and `fullscreen.js` for this project. I need to put the image on top of the screen, while pushing the other content down. Thanks in advance!

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">
        <img id="header1"src="http://placehold.it/1980x720&text=home" class="img-responsive hidden-print hidden-xs" style="position:absolute; vertical-align:top; top:60px;">
        <br />
        <br>
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
<div>
```

Comment: use `"position: absolute" ` to image and `margin-top:200px` to other content

Comment: I tried going something like that, but I have the image set to be hidden on smaller views, and it is adaptive.

Comment: @depperm see the edits I made

Comment: @DaniM.Smith then you can remove the margin on small views as well, right?

Comment: Add `position: relative` to either `#fullpage` or `.section` depending what you want the image relative to

Comment: @DanGamble thank for wanting to help me, but this unfortunately didn't work.  WoodrowBarlow I can't because the image size changes based on the screen size, not just when the view changes to xs, sm, md, or lg

Comment: Just so you know your `vertical-align` isn't what you are after but it's hard to try and understand what you are after.

Comment: People won't be able to help you unless you provide them with a reproduction with the problem in jsfiddle or codepen. Why? Because fullpage.js plugin modifies the DOM structure of your site. And you need to deal with the resulting HTML makrup and not with the initial one.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#fullpage
{
  vertical-align:center;
  padding-top: 273px; /*...height of header image...*/
}

.section
{
  
}

#header1 
{
  position:absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="fullpage">
        <div class="section">
                <img id="header1"src="http://placehold.it/1980x720&text=home" class="img-responsive hidden-print hidden-xs">
            <br />
            <br>
            <h1>Test</h1>
        </div>
    <div>
```

Comment: If you run the code snippet you can see it's pushing the text below the header. If you're issue is that the header has variable sizing, that is easily fixed.

Comment: I see. there must be something in fullscreen.js or Bootstrap preventing this from working

Comment: It doesnt work because fullpage.js modifies the resulting DOM structure. He has to provide us with a reproduction in jsfiddle or codepen.

Answer (score 0):

You should separate your header image from you content using separate divs inside of your fullpage div.
Add absolute position to header-container and top padding to content-container.
You will still need to calculate the center offset if you need to center your absolutely positioned header.

https://jsfiddle.net/st37fuok/4/

```
<div class="section">
    <div id="header-container">
        <img src="http://www.speakdolphin.com/images/headerBar.png" id="header1"/>
    </div>
    <div id="content-container">
        <p>This is some text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I haven't tested this script but something along these lines could give you your left component.

```
function centerAbsolute(){
    var headerWidth = $('#header1').width();
    var pageWidth = window.innerWidth;

    var centerOffset = (pageWidth - headerWidth) / 2;

    $('#header1').css({left: centerOffset});
}
```

Comment: It does not move to the top, unfortunately

Comment: I deleted those tags soon after asking this question, and it is still not working

Comment: I've updated my answer. I am assuming you want this header to reside on the top of the page and not scroll with the fullpage.
You may want to provide a screenshot of the behavior you are seeing if the suggestions from myself and others haven't helped so far.

Comment: It doesnt work because fullpage.js modifies the resulting DOM structure. He has to provide us with a reproduction in jsfiddle or codepen.

Comment: @Alvaro How do I include the fullscreen.js library into JSFifddle?

Comment: I'm trying to replicate it, but I am not able to for some reason

Comment: I pasted the CSS, and the content in the jsfiddle is not centering

Answer (score 0):

<del>Add a margin to the body the height of the image to push the fullpage div down.  When the image is absolute and top 0 it will sit inside the margin.</del>

Add a **padding** to the fullpage the height of the image to push the fullpage div down.  When fullpage is **relative** and image is **absolute** and top 0 it will sit inside the padding.

```css
* {
  vertical-align: center;
}

#fullpage {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding-top:100px;
  width:400px;
  position:relative;
}
#header1 {
  position: absolute;
  vertical-align: top;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section">
    <img id="header1" src="http://placehold.it/400x100&text=home" class="img-responsive hidden-print hidden-xs">
    <br />
    <br>
    <h1>Test</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The header must be inside the fullscreen div. I am using fullscreen.js (http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)

Comment: @DaniM.Smith it's now changed to fit inside the fullpage div.